# Redirecting shell script output to a spreadsheet in sharepoint portal

Tags: scripts, xls

I need to write a shell script that takes some statistics related to system and those values should be redirected to a spreadsheet in share point which then presented as a graph. Which is the best way to redirect output of shell script to spreadsheet in share point that updates dynamically?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

If you need a **xlsx** spreadsheet, take a look at this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/457696/32239) where I present two packages to create such files. A simple script could take your `bash` output to render a spreadsheet. I'd suggest to first look at this simple [example](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JMCNAMARA/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.77/examples/chart_line.pl) (in `perl`).

There is also a well known tool called [RRDtool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool) for such a task:

> RRDtool (acronym for round-robin database tool) aims to handle
>   time-series data like network bandwidth, temperatures, CPU load, etc.
>   The data are stored in a circular buffer based database, thus the
>   system storage footprint remains constant over time.

**RRDtool** can render your system metrics this way:

[image]

Source: http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool